# Linq to merge 2 lists selecting colum

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have 2 lists of string and I am merging them but selecting a specific column.
I managed to get it, but I am sure there is a better way:

```
public List<string> GetAll()
{
    var i = _iRepository.GetAll().Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
    var a = _aRepository.GetAll().Select(x => x.Name);
    i.AddRange(a);
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Do you need the resulting list to have unique elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<string> allNameList = _iRepository.GetAll()
    .Select(x => x.Name)
    .Concat(_aRepository.GetAll().Select(x => x.Name))
    .ToList();
```

If you want to remove duplicates use `Union` instead of `Concat`.

Answer (score 2):

Pull the string out of list one, and concatenate it to the list of string from list 2:

```
 _iRepository.Select(x => x.Name).Concat(_aRepository.Select(x => x.Name)).ToList()
```

ps; I'm not sure how you have 2 lists of string - if `_iRepository` were a list of string, you wouldn't be able to select `x.Name` because a string doesn't have a .Name property! The lists are `List<SomeObjectThatHasANameProperty>`, surely.. ?

Answer (score 0):

Shorter (assuming both GetAll() return the same type) :

```
return _iRepository.GetAll().Concat(_aRepository.GetAll()).Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

A bit more efficient (less memory allocations) if GetAll() returns a new list:

```
var list = _iRepository.GetAll();
list.AddRange(_aRepository.GetAll());
return list.ConvertAll(x => x.Name);
```